# How to get a html tag innerHTML of client side code?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

Using asp.net and c# on a sharepoint server I edit the innerhtml of a div tag that has runat="server", and I place lots of html code in it and an input box (this input box is the autocomplete jquery UI input box).

I can give the input box an id.

Now how can I access the text in the input box in c#?

```
        searchbox.InnerHtml = @"
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(function() {
                        var availableTags = [
                            " + results + @"
                        ];
                        $( '#tags' ).autocomplete({
                            source: availableTags
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <div class='demo'>
                    <div class='ui-widget'>
                        <input id='tags'>
                    </div>
                </div>";
```

Comment: Can you post some code of how you are creating the input box?

Comment: ok i put the code above.

Comment: Are you trying to get the contents of the inputbox to the server side code (c#) or what?

Answer (score 0):

You want an HTML parser. You can try out [this library](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Specifically, if you use Chrome.. right click the box itself and 'Inspect it'. Right click the inputbox, and hit 'Copy XPath'. This is the path, now just select the element with HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: so theres no way to do this without another library?

Comment: There is... if you want to write your own parser. If you just want a quick and dirty parser, that's possible.. but if you're parsing a lot of HTML I can't say I would try it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access to the value of the input box from the server side code. You either need to post it back or send the value of the input box by an Ajax request to the server.

Post back using form & submit

```
<form action="yourpage.aspz" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="inputbox"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And for the Ajax code with JQuery:

```
<input type="text" name="inputbox" id="inputbox"/>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="ajaxPost();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxPost(){
        var inputBoxValue=$("#inputbox").val();
        $.post("yourpage.aspx", { inputbox: inputBoxValue } );
    }
</script>
```

Yourpage.aspx.cs

```
     // ... some other code 
     var a = Request.Form("inputbox")
     // ... some other code
```